# What does block/entity mean, using the /stats command, in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I just wanted to know what /stats is about, in Minecraft 1.8. I have used it, before, but I just can not understand its use.

I know about scoreboards, but I still do not understand what the whole block or entity thing is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[The Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Wiki) has a page dedicated to [Commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands), which has a listing for [/stats](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#stats). There is also a [dedicated /stats tutorial](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_stats), if you wish to learn more.**

To answer your direct query;

"Block" refers to a command block. You set these up to run the code, and they otherwise act as stationary pieces.

"Entity" refers to a player character. Players can use the `/stat` command from the console.